# Azure ContainerApps YAML registry identity

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity, azure-container-registry, azure-container-apps

I am trying to spin up an Azure ContainerApp service via a YAML configuration file. The problem is with the following block:

```
registries:
  - passwordSecretRef: null
    server: xxx.azurecr.io
    identity: "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/mymanagedidentity"
    username: null
```

The error message is the following:

> (InvalidParameterValueInContainerTemplate) The following field(s) are either invalid or missing. Field 'configuration.Registries.xxx.azurecr.io.Identity' is invalid with details: 'Invalid value: "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/mymanagedidentity": Managed Identity does not exist';.

This user-assigned managed does exist and has the AcrPull permission on the acr scope. I can confirm it by running **az identity show --name mymanagedidentity --resource-group xxx --query id --output tsv**

Furthermore, it works perfectly if I create the containerapp via a cli command referencing this managed identity.

```
az containerapp create --registry-identity /subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/mymanagedidentity --registry-server xxx.azurecr.io
```

I would appreciate any input on what might be the issue and how to resolve it!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the following block to the YAML configuration file in order for things to work:
[image]